# What is the Django command to access a related attribute in a many-to-many relationship (not related_name)

Tags: django, many-to-many

In Django, I have a model called Articles. Each article has an attribute called "comments_on". This attribute has a many-to-many relationship with all the articles that it criticizes. The related_name for this attribute is "commented_on_by". This means that if article1 criticizes article2, then article2.commented_on_by will point to article1. My question is how do I get access to article2 from article1? In other words, I'd like to write something like article1.[something] to access article2. Thank you.

Comment: `article1.comments_on` will give you the list of all the articles it criticises. In that list, there will be `article2`. To get that, you'll have to loop over the list.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I was unclear in my question. how do I access the attributes of article2 from article1. For example, I want the title, author, etc of article2, but I want to access those attributes from article1

Comment: Figured it out! You have to iterate over article1.comments_on.all. Thanks for your help, though. It got me closer to the answer.

Comment: `comments_on` isn't a list, it's a manager. Hence needing `all()` to get a queryset of actual items, You can filter further if you have constraints you want to apply, eg `some_article.comments_on.filter(author=some_user)`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to take the query set imagine this are your models

```
 class A(models.model)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)

class B(models.Model)
      name = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
     a = models.ManyToManyField(A, blank=True, null=True)
```

you should query

```
amodels= b.a.all()
```